# Why i(f)stream can't read a double

Tags: c++, io

I'm writing a program and one thing needed to be implemented is to overload `>>` operator for reading a point at once. What I've tried:

```cpp
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, const Point& point)
{
  double temp;
  is >> temp;
  point.setx(temp);
  is.ignore(3,';');
  is >> temp;
  point.sety(temp);
  is.ignore(3,';');
}
```

It somewhy fails to compile in VS2019 (if that matters) with a message that there's no operator `>>` accepting `std::istream` & `double` as arguments. The problem remains with any type `temp`. Either it is an `int` or a `char*` and doesn't depend on whether I read from `istream` or `ifstream`.

What could be a reason for such behaviour and any possible soltion?

Comment: Did you include `<fstream>`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain a [mcve]. Why are `setx` and `sety` `const` functions, surely they change parts of `Point`?

Comment: @Quimby Thx, I've carefully re-checked inclusion sequence and it happened, that one of incorrect header guards stopped fstream from including. Now the question seems so dumb..

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you forgot to `#include <iostream>`? Without that, you'd expect to get an error message like you've cited.

Once you fix that, I'd expect to see a couple of other warnings/errors. First, you're pass `point` by reference to const `Point`, even though `operator>>` seems to be modifying the `Point` that's passed (which is as expected). You probably want to remove the `const`.

Second, you've declared your `operator>>` to return an `std::istream &`, but failed to return anything. You probably want to add `return is;` just before its end.

This code compiles:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point { 
    double x;
    double y;

    void setx(double x_) { x = x_; }
    void sety(double y_) { y = y_; }
};

std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, Point& point)
{
  double temp;
  is >> temp;
  point.setx(temp);
  is.ignore(3,';');
  is >> temp;
  point.sety(temp);
  is.ignore(3,';');
  return is;
}
```